# Rails i18n check if an item exists before display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n, items

I have a basic loop to display items from an i18n list:

```
  <% t('.items').each do |item| %>
    <p><%=item[:description]%></p>
    <p><%=item[:description_html]%></p>
  <%end%>
```

my .yml file is organized as follow:

```
fr:
  pages:
    index:
      items:
      - title: The title
        description: The description 
        description_html: <p> The description with HTML tags</p>
```

Sometimes, the item `description_html` doesn't have any value in my .yml i18n file, so I would like to check first in my code if `description_html` has value before displaying it in my HTML. Any suggestion?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to test whether a translation is available you can use [`I18n.exists?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/svenfuchs/i18n/I18n/Base#exists%3F-instance_method)

For example:

```
<% if I18n.exists?('pages.index.items.description_html') %>
  <%= I18n.t('pages.index.items.description_html') %>
<% end %>
```

If you do just want to display some default output when there is no translation you can add a default as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49996280/120518) with:

```
<%= I18n.t('pages.index.items.description_html', default: 'No description') %>
```

Comment: it seems like the most appropriate answer, but your example is not correct I think. 'I18n.exists?' returns true when fallbacks are considered. What does it mean? Let's say that description_html actually exists, so in your example, the if condition returns false, because the value does exist, and the condition is not met, so nothing happens. But if I add an <%else%> condition, and write '  <%= I18n.t('pages.index.items.description_html') %>' it will succeed. Absolutely not intuitive, isn't it? Seems like this weird behavior was already addressed https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/issues/365

Comment: best solution for this seems to set 'config.i18n.fallbacks = false' in config/application.rb, but it's a pain. Sorry, you example was correct, but one should make sure i18n.fallbacks is correctly configured

Comment: It depends how you use fallbacks. If you've got a fallback for everything then you're covered anyway if there's no value for the key in a locale explicitly.

Comment: In theory, I agree with you. Thing is, I declared 'i18n.fallbacks=false' and even when 'description_html' exists and has a value, when I write <% if I18n.exists?(item[:description_html]) %><%end%>, it returns false, so there's no output... It returns the correct output in the <%else%> block

Comment: OK just found how to make it work. The exists? function weirdly behaves for me, so just need to test if item[:description] is true or false like this: <% if item[:description_html] %><p>exists</p><%else%><p>not exists</p><%end%>